# Create modal window in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Before learning AngularJS I learned jQuery ( + mustache for templates). Now It is difficult to understand how to work with AngularJS...

I am trying to show modal window for user. Early (jQuery) I created a template, parsed it and appended it to the DOM.

In AngularJS, if I understand correctly, there are more than one way to do it. I can use `ngView` directive, `ngInclude` directive, `ngBingHtml` directive, create custom directive with 'templateUrl', and may be something else...

But I dont want to load templates from server on demand, I want to create script section with `type='text/ng-template'` and use it.

First of all I cant understand what the right way to choose, second is how dynamicly change templates (I need put template into directive, work with template, delete template, but not directive... yes?)

Thank a lot.

Comment: There's a big difference between [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [Angular](https://angular.io/). Consider sticking to one throughout your question.

Comment: sorry, AngularJS

Comment: `ng-view` is used once in your app. `ng-include` are usually for small, static components like header/footer. Directives would be your best approach. They can be slightly complicated, so here is an example you can look at: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/big_head/pen/LEKEvm). Alternatively just use something that already exists, like [`ui.bootstrap` modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)

Comment: Ok, I have understand. But does it mean that for every modal window (signin, user settings, others...) I should create their own directive? I cant use one and pass different template to show different modal window?